# magento : get best selling products based on the current product collection

Tags: magento

I am trying to retrieve best seller products using the current product collection by overriding the  Catalog/Product/List.php

```
<?php
 if($this->getRequest()->getParam('best')==1){ 

     $this->_productCollection->getSelect()
          ->joinLeft(array('items'=>'sales_flat_order_item'), "items.product_id = e.entity_id", array('count'=>'SUM(qty_ordered)'))
          ->group('e.entity_id');
     $this->_productCollection->getSelect()->having('SUM(items.qty_ordered) > ?',0);
     return $this->_productCollection;
 }
?>
```

Using the above code I am getting the following SQL error, The error is caused because of the having clause, 
How I can I use the havinh clause in the above code to avoid resultant rows which is having  qty_ordered<1

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'items.qty_ordered' in 'having clause'
```

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to get best selling products

```
$storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image')) //edit to suit tastes
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); //best sellers on top

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

print_r($products->getData());
```

See more @ http://magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14764